# Two inserts in a single trigger

Tags: postgresql, trigger

I have this trigger (audit trigger, in every table I want to audit).

```
CREATE FUNCTION changelog_trigger() RETURNS trigger AS $$
    BEGIN
        IF TG_OP = 'INSERT'
            THEN INSERT INTO "changeLog" (
                "tableName", operation, after, "userId"
                ) VALUES (
                TG_TABLE_NAME, TG_OP, row_to_json(NEW), cast(row_to_json(NEW)::json ->> 'userId' as numeric)
                );
            RETURN NEW;
        ELSIF TG_OP = 'UPDATE'
            THEN INSERT INTO "changeLog" (
                "tableName", operation, before, after, "userId"
                ) VALUES (
                TG_TABLE_NAME,  TG_OP, row_to_json(OLD), row_to_json(NEW), cast(row_to_json(NEW)::json ->> 'userId' as numeric)
                    );
            RETURN NEW;
        ELSIF TG_OP = 'DELETE'
            THEN INSERT INTO "changeLog" (
                "tableName", operation, before, "userId"
                ) VALUES (
                TG_TABLE_NAME, TG_OP, row_to_json(OLD), cast(row_to_json(NEW)::json ->> 'userId' as numeric)
                );
            RETURN OLD;
        END IF;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' SECURITY DEFINER;

CREATE TRIGGER t BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON "Cities" FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE changelog_trigger();
CREATE TRIGGER t BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON "Buildings" FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE changelog_trigger();
CREATE TRIGGER t BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON "Areas" FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE changelog_trigger();
CREATE TRIGGER t BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON "Rooms" FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE changelog_trigger();
CREATE TRIGGER t BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON "Flags" FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE changelog_trigger();
CREATE TRIGGER t BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON "Details" FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE changelog_trigger();
CREATE TRIGGER t BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON "Files" FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE changelog_trigger();
CREATE TRIGGER t BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON "DetailFiles" FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE changelog_trigger();
CREATE TRIGGER t BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON "Users" FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE changelog_trigger();
CREATE TRIGGER t BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON "Infrastructures" FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE changelog_trigger();
CREATE TRIGGER t BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON "Builds" FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE changelog_trigger();
CREATE TRIGGER t BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON "DB_Backups" FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE changelog_trigger();
```

This works perfectly, at least until now. Client wants to also update a record which states the last time anything was updated. I thought about adding a second insert after THEN. Is this the best approach? I need to update, in table Cities, column updatedAt, with the timestamp of the operation.

I thought about doing this but I want to be sure because this is a production server and I'm not a DBA by any stretch.

```
        IF TG_OP = 'INSERT'
            THEN INSERT INTO "changeLog" (
                "tableName", operation, after, "userId"
                ) VALUES (
                TG_TABLE_NAME, TG_OP, row_to_json(NEW), cast(row_to_json(NEW)::json ->> 'userId' as numeric)
                );
            UPDATE "Cities" SET "updatedAt" = current_timestamp() where id = 1;
            RETURN NEW;
```

Is this correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the trigger defined on the `Cities` table? Please **[edit]** your question and add the complete code of the function and the `create trigger` statement. ([edit] your question, please do not put code in comments)

Comment: If the client wants to "**update** a record which states the last time", why `insert`?

Comment: @mustaccio because it was 2 in the morning. It was a brainfart. I meant update.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'll edit my question. The triggers are defined in every table, because I want them to trigger on every change on every table. Cities table doesn't have a trigger yet.

Comment: Surely the trigger has to update the `updatedAt` column on the table it is being called from, and not always that on `Cities`? In that case you can just do `new.updatedAt = now();` anywhere in the trigger body.

Comment: @Colin'tHart the audit trigger (this one I posted) is in every table I want audited. At any changes on those tables, I need to write to changelog table AND update the Cities table, updatedAt column, with the timestamp. This might be a problem because it will create a loop (the Cities table also have the trigger, so when I updated Cities, it will trigger, which will update the Cities, which will update the trigger...)

Comment: That’s why you reference `new`.

Comment: But I need to update the record on Cities AND changeLog, doesn't matter where the change was made. So referencing new will reference the altered table, not Cities, right?